# Emulator with Google Play Certification

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator, emulators

I am looking for an Android emulator that has been authorized by Google to include Play and other apps. One I am looking into is called Andy.

Is Andy authorized to use GApps? If not, are there any emulators authorized to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Android package GMS will be only available on devices certifieds by google.. I think it will be hard to find officially

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the images provided by the Android-X86 project. They run fine in Virtualbox, and ship with Google Apps pre-installed. For details, please see:

- [Android emulator for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6892/185) (on our sister-site for Software Recommendations)
- [How to install Android in Virtualbox](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/) at HowtoGeek
- [Android Emulators](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=48) at IzzyOnDroid (my site; scroll to the end of the page for emulations *OF* Android, as the list starts with emulators running *on* Android ;))
- find [Android-x86 ISO](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list) images on their Google Code site